# Replace STC12C5A60S2 with Rasberry Pi Pico

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

I have an 8x8x8 LED cube from Geekcreit which is driven by an STC12C5A60S2 programmable controller.

I fancy replacing this controller with a Raspberry Pi Pico in order to be able to program it using current tools and, perhaps enable WiFi connectivity, etc.

I plan to make a simple board to map the Pico pin-out to the STC socket pins. I hope I won't need any additional chips, etc.

I was wondering if anyone knew of similar projects or of any gotchas I need to know.

Comment: It's usually not so difficult to drive such a thing from a different CPU, though it almost certainly won't go on the original PCB.  You're going to need the circuit diagram of your existing cube.  Can you post it here?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... this site is not a forum ... it is a Q&A site

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Raspberry+Pi+LED+cube&ia=web

Comment: `I am hoping that I wont need any additional chips` ... why do you say that? ... is that a question in disguise?

Answer (score 1):

If your kit is like [this one](https://www.instructables.com/Assembling-the-Geekcreit-8x8x8-LED-Cube-3D-Light-S/), you stand a decent chance.  According to that instructable post, the circuit diagram is wrong in a number of ways, but the basic gist is:

- A CPU with three 8-bit outputs
- One feeds an ULN2803 darlington array ("switches to Vcc") P0
- One feeds eight 74LS573 latches, bussed together P1
- One feeds the eight latch LE signals P2
- The latches form a plane of 8x8 LEDs

It's got to be something like this:
[image]
Basically the software puts out the value for each latch on the bus, latches it into a particular latch, and switches on the appropriate darlington drivers.

As the Pi Pico has more than 24 GPIO pins, you should be able to do it, by careful mapping of all the IO pins.

To do your task,

1. Work out the *actual* circuit and draw it up.
2. Understand how it works by reading the datasheets for [ULN2803](https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/389/uln2801a-1852595.pdf) and [74LS573](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc573a.pdf).
3. Write some software to try it!  Try lighting just one LED at a time.

Good lcuk and enjoy your project.